# Missing Permissions error when changing nicknames in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Every time I try to change the nickname of someone else in my server using my bot (or even myself in a friend's server for that matter), it fails, giving me the following error:

```
(node:11620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\(User)\Desktop\Discord Bot\Nick-Cycle\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:11620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I checked, and it does have Manage Nicknames, and it's role is just beneath owner.  The person i'm trying to change the nickname of, his highest role is far beneath the bot's.

[Image of Bot's role, position, and Manage Nickname's permission.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6jHf.png)

Here's the code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    const prefix = ";"

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    switch(cmd) {
        case "setnick": 
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")) return message.channel.send("I don't have Manage Nicknames!");
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Not enough arguments!");
        if (args[0] === getUserFromMention(args[0])) {
            const user = getUserFromMention(args[0])
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Not enough arguments!");

            message.guild.members.fetch(user).setNickname(args[1]);
        }
        else {
            message.member.setNickname(args[0]);
        }
        break;
    }
    
});

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
 if (!mention) return;

 if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
  mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

  if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
   mention = mention.slice(1);
  }

  return client.users.cache.get(mention);
 }
}
```

What's wrong?  Is it a glitch? Is there something wrong in the roles?  Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: If member has higher role position, so you can`t change this member nickname.

Comment: as far as i know, i'm using the latest version of Discord.js.  and i tried changing the nick of someone who had a lower role than the bot, i checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It turns out it wasn't taking in the arguments like it should, and kept diverting to the Else, where it changes your own nick, and in my server, i am owner, where my nick can't be changed by bots. Fixed it by rewriting the if statements to check for a mention specifically before continuing on. Works now!

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Your code isn't the issue. The problem is how your bot role is positioned as well as what permissions it has. Make sure that the bot has the ability to change the names of other people and it's role is above the victim's role. Hope this helps!

[image]

Turn this on

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issue either...  I've edited my original post with an image of the bot's role and the Manage Nicknames permission.  I've got no clue why it's doing this...  It should have everything it needs...

Comment: Who's nickname are you trying to change?

Comment: a lower person in my server.  I'm server owner, and the test subject is low in roles.

Comment: I've also tried changing the nicks of other bots in my server, also to no avail...